# Elegantly pairing up mismatched lists

Tags: list-manipulation, histograms

`HistogramList` returns a list of bin boundaries and a list of counts.  There is one more boundary than counts, and I'd like to pair them up so I can feed it into `ListLinePlot` and get an alternative view of a histogram.  Here's some code that will do this:

```
{bins, counts} = N[HistogramList[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 2], 100]]]

(* => {{0., 2., 4., 6., 8., 10.}, {13., 19., 37., 28., 3.}} *)

points = Transpose[{Riffle[bins, bins], Flatten[{0, Riffle[counts, counts], 0}]}]

(* => {{0., 0}, {0., 13.}, {2., 13.}, {2., 19.}, {4., 19.}, {4., 37.}, {6., 37.}, 
       {6., 28.}, {8., 28.}, {8., 3.}, {10., 3.}, {10., 0}} *)
```

Note that it also adds in some zeros to bring the resulting curve down to the axis:

```
ListLinePlot[points]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there a simpler and/or more intuitive way of achieving this behavior?

Comment: +1, I'm at a complete loss as to how to improve this. Although, I believe `Thread` may be faster than `Transpose` for longer lists.

Comment: You could use `ArrayPad[]` for starters: `Transpose[{Riffle[bins, bins], ArrayPad[Riffle[counts, counts], 1]}]`

Comment: Another way: `Transpose[{Riffle[bins, bins], Flatten[Partition[counts, 2, 1, {-1, 1}, 0]]}]`

Comment: @J.M.  Why are you answering in comments?!

Comment: @rcollyer I'm not too concerned about speed in this case, but really?  I'll have to test that out...

Comment: Ooh, I'd forgotten about `ArrayPad`.

Comment: I felt that maybe you just forgot about `ArrayPad[]`...

Comment: It has been awhile since I tested it, but I believe `Thread` wins, especially on longer lists. For short lists, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J. M. left a solution in a comment that I really like, so I'm creating an answer out of it:

```
points = Transpose[{Riffle[bins, bins], ArrayPad[Riffle[counts, counts], 1]}]
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `InterpolationOrder` for the plot itself to generate the same behavior. I'm assuming here you want the plot you posted in an easier way, not the data handling itself.

```
{bins, counts} = HistogramList[...];
ListLinePlot[
    {bins, Append[counts, 0]} // Transpose, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 0
]
```

[image]

(You may want to prepend one value to the finished list so that the histogram goes down to zero on the left side as well.)

Comment: Really clever usage of InterpolationOrder -> 0 ;-)

Comment: Alternatively: `Plot[Evaluate[Piecewise[Transpose[{counts, #1 < t <= #2 & @@@ Partition[bins, 2, 1]}], 0]], {t, First[bins], Last[bins]}, Exclusions -> None]`.

Answer (score 6):

In the same vein as Andy's answer: `Differences[ArrayPad[counts, 1]].UnitStep[x - bins]` can be used with `Plot[]`. Apply `PiecewiseExpand[]` if need be.

Comment: For those wondering why this works, I gave a mathematical explanation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/54750).

Answer (score 6):

What about this to create the points?

```
points = Flatten[Through[{PadLeft, PadRight}[{bins, counts}]], {{3, 1}}]
```

Comment: +1 This is awesomely awesome, though unfortunately not intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing it (although, I don't think it fits the "intuitive" part), is:

```
(Outer[List, {#1}, #2] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{bins, 
     Partition[ArrayPad[counts, 1], 2, 1, {1, -1}]}]) ~Flatten~ 2
```

One could also do it using `MapIndexed` and naïve pairing as

```
With[{counts1 = ArrayPad[counts, 1]}, 
  MapIndexed[{{#1, First@counts1[[#2]]}, {#1, First@counts1[[#2 + 1]]}} &, bins]
  ] ~Flatten~ 1
```

Comment: That's a creative use of `Outer[]`. I like!

Comment: Unfortunately this is much slower than `Transpose[{Riffle[bins, bins], ArrayPad[Riffle[counts, counts], 1]}]`

Comment: Okay, it's not, but I also don't find this elegant.  Sorry. :-/

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use `Plot` instead of `ListLinePlot` then something like this would work and matches up with the style of the PDF in `HistogramDistribution`:

```
f[bins_, counts_][x_] := Boole[Thread[Most[bins] <= x < Rest[bins]]].counts
```

Comment: If taking this approach I think it would be better to construct a `Piecewise` function.

Comment: Equivalently: `Piecewise[Transpose[{counts, Thread[Most[bins] <= x < Rest[bins]]}], 0]`. Or maybe even `Which @@ Join[Riffle[Thread[Most[bins] <= x < Rest[bins]], counts], {True, 0}]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1]
{bins, counts} = N[HistogramList[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 2], 100]]];

ListStepPlot[Transpose[{Most @ bins, counts}], Filling -> {1 -> 0}]  /. 
  p_Polygon :> {EdgeForm[Blue], p}
```

[image]

For equal-spaced bins,

```
ListStepPlot[counts, Filling -> Axis, DataRange -> MinMax[Most @ bins]] /. 
  p_Polygon:>{EdgeForm[Blue],p}
```

gives the same result.