# Better method for creating a tuple out of two lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I just combined two lists using this method

```
molefrac = {1., 0.787402, 0.478927, 0.282592, 0.}
calibrationIndexOfRefraction = {1.440, 1.421, 1.395, 1.380, 1.351}
Partition[Riffle[molefrac, calibrationIndexOfRefraction], 2]
```

> ```
> {{1., 1.44}, {0.787402, 1.421}, {0.478927, 1.395}, {0.282592, 1.38}, {0., 1.351}}
> ```

The purpose of this was to prepare the lists to be plotted using `ListPlot`. Is there some way to use `ListPlot` directly (or something more functional) to do this without going through all the extra steps?

Comment: What is `molefrac` ? And why do you have so many and btw unbalanced parenthesis in the 1st line?

Comment: Why don't you use `newList = Transpose[{molefrac, calibrationIndexOfRefraction}]`. You will get the same result as above on a more straightforward way. This can be plotted easily with `ListPlot[newList]`. Or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @partial81 bill s beat us both (and kguler) to that answer. :-)

Comment: Related, though with lists of different lengths: [Elegantly pairing up mismatched lists](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/324/89).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{molefrac, calibrationIndexOfRefraction}]]
```

You can look at the help file for `ListPlot` to see the plotting options to make it look the way you wish.

Comment: +1 -- In the FrontEnd this is extremely concise: `ListPlot[{molefrac, calibrationIndexOfRefraction}\[Transpose]]`

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution:

```
ListPlot[Thread[List[molefrac, calibrationIndexOfRefraction]]]
```

or

```
ListPlot[{molefrac, calibrationIndexOfRefraction}//Thread]
```