# Removing a histogram's vertical edges

Tags: histograms

Let's say I have a histogram:

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I remove vertical lines inside the histogram and keep only the edge?

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/324/280

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The underlying problem is that `Histogram` creates a set of `Rectangles` which represent the bars. You can inspect this by looking at the underlying form of the created graphics

```
h = Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500], 
  Automatic, "PDF", PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];
InputForm[h]
```

This reveals that each bar in the histogram is represented as

```
Rectangle[{5., 0}, {6., 3/125}, "RoundingRadius" -> 0]
```

Now the hard part becomes visible, because although you can set the `EdgeForm` of each `Rectangle`, you cannot easily make it so that the whole histogram has a surrounding edge. You can solve the issue by using some trickery as @MarcoB did in his answer. This is a perfectly fine solution.

Another way is to extract the points that define the given rectangles and use them to create *one* polygon which represents all bars. If you give this polygon a black edge, then it will show what you like. Then you draw this polygon over your existing Histogram:

```
adjust[gr_] := Show[
  gr,
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black}], FaceForm[RGBColor[0.98, 0.81, 0.49]], 
    Polygon[Cases[gr, 
       Rectangle[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, _] :> 
        Sequence[{x1, y1}, {x1, y2}, {x2, y2}, {x2, y1}], 
       Infinity] //. {s___, a_, a_, e___} :> {s, e}]}]
  ]
adjust[h]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much for a nice solution

Answer (score 23):

I think you could achieve what you want by overlaying two `Histogram` objects, one with no Edges but colored bars, the second one with Edges, but transparent bars, as in this example:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500];
Show[{
    Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0], EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[4]]]],
    Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[None]]
}]
```

Here is the result:

[image: Overlaid histograms]

Comment: I recommend that you add your actual figure to your Answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you, that's an excellent idea. This being my first answer on this site, it took me a while to figure out how to add the image, but it should be there now!

Comment: @MarcoB If you want to easily upload images, please have a look at the [SE Tools](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1521/187) package which has an easy-to-use palette to simply mark and upload images directly from within a notebook.

Comment: @halirutan Thank you for the pointer. Your `SETools` package looks like a fantastic collection of handy tools! Now I see how the pros do it (-:

Answer (score 8):

You can also `Plot` the scaled `PDF` of the `HistogramDistribution` of `data`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500];
hd = HistogramDistribution[data];

{min, max, length} = Through@{Min, Max, Length}@data;
Plot[Evaluate[length PDF[hd, x]], {x, min - 2, max + 2}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {min - 2, 0}, Exclusions -> None, PlotStyle -> Thick, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I offer a solution that uses a simpler technique:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500];
hist = HistogramList[data];

hist[[2]] = hist[[2]]~Join~{0};

ListLinePlot[Transpose[hist], InterpolationOrder -> 0,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Black], Filling -> Axis,
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.8]]]
```

[image]

`HistogramList` gets you a list of bin start and end points, and counts/heights.  It has the same bin options and height options as `Histogram` so you can get the same data.

Since it is giving bin start and end points there will be one more entry in the bin list then in the counts/height list. Therefore I add on a zero to the end of the counts list to make them the same size. This is so the plot returns to zero at the end of the last bin and so that `Transpose` works on the list.

In `ListLinePlot` setting `InterpolationOrder->0` will get your plot with straight line steps. Select the `PlotStyle` that you want and the `FillingStyle` as well.

The coding is not as exciting as the other but it works just the same.

---

**Update with example for multiple datasets (I was curious)**

I've added a helper function as it was pointed out in the comments that the first "bar" does not rise up from zero but starts at its height value leaving the first edge without a line.

```
{data1, data2} =
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[Sequence @@ #], 500] & /@ {{12, 2}, {20, 3}};
{hist1, hist2} = HistogramList[#] & /@ {data1, data2};

histPlotAdjust[histList_] :=
 Module[{bins, counts},
  With[{binLength = histList[[1, 2]] - First@histList[[1]]},
   bins = {First@histList[[1]] - binLength}~Join~histList[[1]];
   counts = {0}~Join~histList[[2]]~Join~{0};
   {bins, counts}
   ]]

hist1 = histPlotAdjust[hist1];
hist2 = histPlotAdjust[hist2];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[#] & /@ {hist1, hist2},
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Black],
 Filling -> Axis,
 FillingStyle -> {1 -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.6]],
   2 -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.6]]}]
```

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please note that you have lost the first vertical line of the histogram (at `x=3`). On your plot it can't be seen but with `data = RandomReal[{3, 17}, 500]` it becomes obvious.

Comment: Ah, need to add a zero on to the front with an addition bin start point.

Comment: You can use `_~Append~0` or `_~Prepend~0` instead of `_~Join~{0}`.  A couple more characters, but a little cleaner than a singleton list.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Updated with vertical line on first bin for multiple dataset example.

Comment: @Edmund In your updated code subtracting `binLength` is not needed: without it you get the correct histogram without unnecessary horizontal line before the histogram.

Comment: @Edmund In other words, `ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Prepend[#,First@#]&@hlist[[1]],ArrayPad[hlist[[2]],1]}],InterpolationOrder->0]` is sufficient. In any case, good idea, +1!

Answer (score 6):

The straightforward solution is to construct the histogram from the list of bins and histogram heights returned by `HistogramList` (on which `Histogram` is based) explicitly:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500];
hlist = HistogramList[data, Automatic, "PDF"];

Graphics[{RGBColor[1, 0.8, 0.5], EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[Small]}],
  Polygon[
   Join[{{hlist[[1, 1]], 0}},
    Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[{Partition[hlist[[1]], 2, 1], hlist[[2]]}], 1],
    {{hlist[[1, -1]], 0}}]
         ]},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> True,
 PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {0, Scaled[0.05]}}]
```

[image: plot]

Or shorter:

```
Graphics[{RGBColor[1, 0.8, 0.5], EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[Small]}],
  Polygon[
   Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[{Partition[hlist[[1]], 2, 1, {-1, 1}, {}], 
       ArrayPad[hlist[[2]], 1]}], 1]
         ]},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> True,
 PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {0, Scaled[0.05]}}]
```

Even shorter and better solution:

```
Graphics[{RGBColor[1, 0.8, 0.5], EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[Small]}],
  Polygon[
   Transpose[{Riffle[#,#]&@hlist[[1]],
     ArrayPad[Riffle[#,#]&@hlist[[2]],1]}]
         ]},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> True,
 PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {0, Scaled[0.05]}}]
```

... and a code-golf version of the working part of the code:

```
Transpose[{#1, ArrayPad[#2, 1]} & @@ (#~Riffle~# & /@ hlist)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use `SmoothHistogram` which is all edge and gets you into the 21st century:

```
SmoothHistogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500]]
```

[image: Smooth histogram]